# Record command into bash source block using asciinema and org-babel

Tags: org-babel, term

As you perhaps know, [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/) rec (`asciinema rec path/to/file`) and generate an [asciicast file](https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema/blob/master/doc/asciicast-v2.md) which contain all commands recorded on terminal.

I think using asciinema to replay this file (`asciinema play /path/to/file.cast`) in exported html was an interesting way for user to replay command with realist color, prompt shell, output log, etc.

Into a bash source block, i try to run the asciicema rec command, but nothing happen.

```
#+NAME: bashwithasciinema
#+BEGIN_SRC bash 
asciicema rec myfile
mkdir "foo"
cd foo/
mkdir "bar
cd bar/
exit
#+END_SRC
```

Any idea of the problem ? Is it linked to shell management ?

Comment: What has this to do with Tramp?

Comment: You're right, i remove the tag, a mistake probably